# No connectivity on Windows

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

My girlfriend laptop suddenly stopped having connectivity. Whether or not she uses Wi-Fi or Ethernet, Windows shows that everything is fine, has an IP address obtained by our home router, the Ethernet LEds light up, but there is no connectivity. Can´t even ping the router that leased the IP. Absolutely everything is blocked. I tried

- Disabling and re enabling both adapters
- Using a external USB Wi-Fi
- Resetting the TCP/IP stack
- Connecting to a neighbor router
- Replacing the Ethernet cable
- Disabling the firewall
- Disabling/enabling both adapters on BIOS

At all times, Windows reports everything is fine but nothing goes out the laptop. Something is blocking all outgoing traffic. I still have to try:

- Virus check
- Linux boot
- Ping the laptop

Of course, all other devices have connectivity, so is not the router.

Comment: Looks like you blocked yourself on the router, Check here: 192.168.1.1

Comment: You might want to add a question to your statements

Comment: Do you have any VPN clients installed? Are there any virtual network adapters in ncpa.cpl?

Answer (score 1):

> My girlfriend laptop suddenly stopped having connectivity. Weather or
> not she uses wifi or ethernet,  ....   I tried many things including
> ....   Resetting the TCP/IP stack

Something has gone quite wrong.

**(1) Try resetting your router.** This is worth doing, but you did say no connectivity on friend's router.

**(2) Try DISM and SFC (although no sure thing here)**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**(3) If DISM does not fix the issue,** try a new, test Windows User Profile (Account).  Settings, Accounts and make a new Account. Make it a member of Administrators (in case needed).

Log into the new Account and test Ethernet connections. If that works, the existing User Profile is damaged and needs to be replaced.

**(4) If User Profile is good, do a Windows 10 Repair Install**

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair and proceed
> normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything to begin with.

Comment: Thanks John. Something is very very weird. The machine started getting internet access after (2). It took a long time but after running, the laptop had internet connection. I ran the other two, and after rebooting...there was no connection. I issued the commands again. This time (2) ran very fast, but there was no internet access after running all commands. In other words, (2) fixed the issue temporally

Answer (score 1):

#### No connectivity on Windows

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated (run as Adminstrator) `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults (reboot required):

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`